# How can I format command arguments which themselves are a group of commands with Python's subprocess module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

Command to run inside `MyCWD` (variable capturing working directory):
`vagrant ssh -c "cd /Path/To/Dir && ./my-shell-script.sh -d argD -f argF"`

I tried doing this but didn't work:

```
vagrantCmd = ['vagrant','ssh','-c', 
              'cd', '/Path/To/Dir', '&&', 
              './my-shell-script.sh', '-d', '-argD', '-f', 'argF']

output,error = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=MyCWD).communicate()
```

However, if I do this, it just works:

```
argCmd = ['cd', '/Path/To/Dir', '&&', 
          './my-shell-script.sh', '-d', '-argD', '-f', 'argF']
os.chdir(MyCWD)
os.system('vagrant ssh -c "%s"' % ' '.join(argCmd))
```

The latter seems to be a lot *easier* but `os.system` is no longer recommended. How can a I get this to work with `subprocess.Popen()`?

I build out the array (`argCmd`) depending on some settings. Basically I build out such arrays and then try pass them to `subprocess.Popen` but such weird string building always has me bang my head with that module, but is rather trivial with `os.system`. How do you work with strings and `subprocess` effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do with your Python code:

```
vagrant ssh -c cd /Path/To/Dir && ./my-shell-script.sh -d argD -f argF
```

What you need:

```
vagrant ssh -c "cd /Path/To/Dir && ./my-shell-script.sh -d argD -f argF"
```

How to fix it?

```
vagrantCmd = ['vagrant','ssh','-c', 
          ' '.join(['cd', '/Path/To/Dir', '&&', 
          './my-shell-script.sh', '-d', '-argD', '-f', 'argF'])]
```

Comment: I did try that...but nothing worked for some reason - it seems the join doesn't include double quotes for subprocess to take in...

Comment: I fixed it, @PhD

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
ok = ['vagrant', 'ssh', '-c']
v = '"{}"'.format 
sub = 'cd /Path/To/Dir && ./my-shell-script.sh -d -argD -f argF'
ok.append(v(pipes.quote(sub)))
```

and:

```
subprocess.Popen(ok)
```

see:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote
- [How to escape os.system() calls in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls-in-python)
- [Putting nested bash command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781421/putting-nested-bash-command-in-python)

... basically wrappers of escaped escaping. Maybe a decorator? Or something fancy, like that.